# What different meanings this sentence has by using the past conditional or the present conditional?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

I'm having trouble in understanding the different meanings of using the past conditional or the present conditional for this sentence.

- Je n’aurais jamais cru que vous vous seriez contentées de si peu.
- Je n’aurais jamais cru que vous vous contenteriez de si peu.

"I would never have thought that you would settle for so little." is the approximate meaning, I think. But which tense is really grammatical and what difference in meaning do they have?

Answer (score 1):

La différence entre ces deux phrases est une question d'interprétation de la part de l'interlocuteur et du contexte dans lequel elles sont exprimées.

Voici mon interprétation :

> Je n’aurais jamais cru que vous vous seriez contentées de si peu.

Après avoir négocié quelque chose, elles ont annoncé qu'il n'était pas nécessaire d'en avoir autant. Leur interlocuteur leur répond *qu'il n'aurait jamais cru qu'elles se seraient contentées de si peu.*

> Je n’aurais jamais cru que vous vous contenteriez de si peu.

Elles étaient en train de négocier quelque chose, et n'ont pas demandé beaucoup comparé à ce que l'interlocuteur prévoyait, et il leur dit *qu'il n'aurait jamais cru qu'elles se contenteraient de si peu*.

---

Le point à souligner ici est le moment où cette phrase est exprimée, une **après** les négociations, l'autre **pendant** les négociations.